# Widening table cell with inline CSS styles not working

Tags: html, css

I have a table with various kinds of data, and the cell widths are uneven.

[image]

I'm having trouble changing the styling of these cells.

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Embed Code</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

<?php

...

echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['description']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['embed']."</td>";
        =echo "<td><a href=delete-sound.php?id=".$row['id'].">Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";

?>
```

I've tried changing the width of this whole column of data at the top of the column - the `th`:

```
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 200px;">Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Embed Code</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
```

That doesn't seem to work, though.

I've also tried doing this to each iterated cell within that column, like this:

```
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style=/"width: 200px;/">".$row['title']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['description']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['embed']."</td>";
        =echo "<td><a href=delete-sound.php?id=".$row['id'].">Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

That also doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP please. We also need any CSS. see [mcve]

Comment: The CSS is inline. I'll fix the PHP - I just figured that maybe it being echoed from PHP might cause issue that I'm not aware of.

Comment: do        <th style="min-width: 200px;">Title</th>

Comment: It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/ozxnLcfL/

Comment: @techLove that did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although I saw that a comment helped you, there's another solution as well.

Just style the table with `style="table-layout:fixed;"`.

The problem with tables is that the cells' width is set arbitrarily based on content width in default tables - this is what is fixed with the style I mentioned before.